# MDB not receving message from consumer

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, ejb

I start the consumer and producer but the MDB does not receive the message.

I used similar code in another application and it works. with this application the mdb is never called and I don't understand if it's a configuration problem (I don't know what to change) or code.

MDB:

```
public class changeRistMDB implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {        
        try {
            RistDTO order = message.getBody(RistDTO.class);
            System.out.println("Expensive order receivede: " + order);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

CONSUMER:

```
public class ChangeConsumer {
    public static void main (String [] args ) throws NamingException {        
        Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/javaee7/ConnectionFactoryRist");
        Destination topic = (Destination) jndiContext.lookup("jms/javaee7/TopicRist");       
        System.out.println("\n Infinite loop. Waiting...");        
        try (JMSContext jmsContext = connectionFactory.createContext()) {
            while(true) {
                RistDTO order = jmsContext.createConsumer(topic).receiveBody(RistDTO.class);
                System.out.println("Order received: " + order);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PRODUCER:

```
public class ChangeProducer {    
    public static void main (String [] args ) throws NamingException {        
        RistDTO order =  new RistDTO("1",-200);
        Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();        
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup("jms/javaee7/ConnectionFactoryRist");
        Destination topic = (Destination) jndiContext.lookup("jms/javaee7/TopicRist");   
        try ( JMSContext jmsContext = connectionFactory.createContext()) {
            jmsContext.createProducer().send(topic, order);
        }
    }
}
```

Producer and Consumer work but MDB does not receive.

Comment: You should add the annotations or deployment descriptor for your MDB, also how it is packaged. And what is the server you use?

Comment: your code looks ok, but your MDB must be configured for this connection factory and topic. Can you also post your MDB configuratoin ?